# Kv related question - How to bound an on_press/release function to the viewclass of the recycleview?

Tags: user-interface, android-recyclerview, kivy, kivy-language

I've been working on a project which required me to learn kv.
what I'm trying to do is use recycleview to display a list of people that are a part of a dataset I built and allow easy edit of the dataset.

what I've done is read the documentation and simply use the first example from there (with a slight change, the viewclass being a togglebutton:
[The Example][1]

so as for my question, what I want to do is simply bound an on_press/release function to the viewclass objects, for example what I want to do is to bound a function to all of the toggle buttons which appends the button's text to a list when It's being pressed and removes the name from the list when It's being released.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55FlM.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding the `on_press` to the `data`:

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.list = []
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'on_press':partial(self.toggle, str(x))} for x in range(100)]

    def toggle(self, name):
        print('toggle')
        if name in self.list:
            self.list.remove(name)
        else:
            self.list.append(name)
        print('list is now:', self.list)
```